# What files do I need to remove to wipe every trace of iTunes from my Mac filesystem?

Tags: itunes

I would like to delete every possible file read, created or cached by iTunes on a Mac and reinstall the whole thing from scratch.

What do I need to delete? Obviously everything in `/Applications/iTunes.app`, what else? Here are some:

- ~/Library/iTunes
- ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iTunes

Also files that iTunes uses, like (I am assuming) the various sync folders and services. What other folders/files am I missing?

Comment: are you using a mac?

Comment: yep- updated question to make that clear.

Comment: The reason I ask is because iTunes is hard coded in the operating system, much like how windows used to hard code IE into the OS. You will have to do a reinstall of the OS

Comment: soulshined: This is not correct, I was able to remove the application and reinstall it from apple.com a few weeks ago. I wasn't thorough in deleting all files however.

Comment: I did not say you couldn't delete it. I'm aware, it's possible, but it is still hard coded into the OS. I'm assuming you ran a sudo command? If so do you recall which one?

Comment: Then you are using 'hard coded' wrong. It's not hard-coded if the OS can function without it. Which it can (although I would  not recommend forcing OSX apps out of the system, it can cause miscellaneous problems). I suppose you also want to remove the `~/Music/iTunes` folder with the track database and all that.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain your problem. Why do you need to 'delete every possible file'? What problem are you encountering when just reinstalling iTunes?

Comment: Did you try a full restore yet?

Comment: Yes. Four times iTunes has turned 25GB of music on my phone into 25GB of undeletable "Other", and I've restored the device  four times in the past week.

Answer (score -1):

The ones I know of are:

`~/Library/iTunes/`

`/Library/iTunes/`

`~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync`

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist` + more similar `.plist` files

However there are probably a LOT more hidden throughout the OS. As soulshined pointed out there are parts of the OS that depend on having iTunes, and removing it would break them. I am curious as to why you need to?

Comment: Which parts of the OS depend on iTunes?

Comment: Because I still haven't solved http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/162525/7087 yet and it's driving me nuts.